# Would you recommend a Raspberry Pi as a remote file backup device?

Tags: backup

I'd like to have a computer at home that I `rsync` my files to from anywhere, preferably at any time I choose. The daily volume of data will rarely exceed 100M. It needs to be cheap and easy to replace, not fast (it's for backup/archiving purposes only).

One idea is to use a Raspberry Pi with a USB hard disk.  (Or two.)
Would you? Can you list any drawbacks that make alternatives obviously superior?

Comment: Absolutely, but be aware you will probably need a powered USB hub for the drives (if they are not self-powered), as the pi ports only deliver 140 mA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also think this is a good setup. I currently do run a Raspberry Pi, connected directly with a 3.5'' USB 2.0 hard disk (Western Digital, 1.5 TB) with external power, and it works like a charm: I get hourly backups when I'm home, and the Raspberry is also an excellent file/media server.

I get 23MB/s instead of 30MB/s on the hard disk, but that's still quite good.
I can stream movies off the hard disk (through Samba or MiniDLNA) without problems.

In fact, the hourly backups are done from my laptop using Apple Time Machine, but using `rsync` shouldn't change much.

As **@goldilocks** mentioned, hard disks without external power (like most 2.5'' hard disk) will require a powered hub: my Raspberry **shuts down** as soon as I try attaching one directly (**edit**: that was with a 5V-1.2A power supply, but still happens when attaching directly with a 5V-2A power supply; a powered hub solves the problem).

In addition, I've installed BarracudaDrive (http://barracudadrive.com/), available for free from the PiStore, which I'll use as my personal cloud in the future.

### Hard disk reliability

The USB HD powers down when not used, but this is implemented by the HD enclosure (most recent ones I bought have this).

Note that spinning down and up is a stress in itself for the hard disk if done too often, but since you can't set the spindown timeout, this is only a problem if the producer chose the wrong setup.

(Google for "ubuntu destroys hard disk" to find discussions such as: https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Known_issues#Drives_which_perform_frequent_head_unloads_under_Linux).

Anyway, you should simply use a reliable USB hard disk designed for your kind of scenarios. Or two ones in mirroring (**edit**: but I would check performance first, since mirroring would double the required USB bandwidth for the same amount of writes).

Instead of mirroring, I carry a rugged hard disk always with me and do backups also there.

### General software setup tips

Of course, you should pay attention to the filesystem you use on the HD: nowadays ext4 is probably the safest choice since it's easiest to recover it.

You might want to use `rdiff-backup` instead of `rsync`, to have access to historic backups.

Finally, since you'll probably do rsync over SSH, you might want to select the RC4 cipher for extra speed (**edit**: but see the warnings about security [in this other answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5198/4395) if you do that over the Internet). Here's an excerpt from my .ssh/config on my host:

```
Host pibbw # Replace pibbw with the hostname of your Raspberry Pi
        User pi
        Ciphers arcfour128
```

Comment: How do you measure the hard disk speed? I'm getting less than 2.5 MB/s on Samba transfers from the hard disk.

Comment: IIRC, 23 and 30 MB/s come from hdparm. But I have to retract my statement about streaming... (More from a non-mobile device).

Answer (score 6):

I've boxed one of my Raspberry with a micro USB hub and a 500GB HD to backup critical directories of my 2TB NAS via rsync. (Just the ones that I cannot afford to lose).

Both the Rpi and the hub are powered by a 5V-2A power adapter (7€). Everything works very well.

I'm so satisfied that I've bought a 2 slots USB HD dock like the one [here](https://www.spire.co.uk/product_details.php?spire_code=HDD-X2USB2&description=SPIRE%20HARD%20DRIVE%20DOCKING%20STATION,%20DUAL%20SLOT,%202.5). One of these days I'll buy a couple of large HD and will move everything there.

BTW, I also plan to install [OwnCloud](http://owncloud.org/) and make it accessible from Internet so to have my own personal Dropbox-like system.

Comment: Does the HD power down when not in use? It will reduce power consumption and wear and tear to a fraction, but I'm not sure how to make sure that it will - will the Raspberry Pi need to support it in some way?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I would say yes.

Comment: Do you actually mean a 500MB HD?

Comment: Most of my modern HD enclosures power down when not used, independently of the system they're connected to.

Comment: @Blaisorblade, ops! Of course, I meant GB :)

Answer (score 1):

I am already using the Raspberry Pi to back up my html directory and mysql tables. Details are available in my blog!

http://ahmet.tekelioglu.org/en/raspberry-pi-backup-and-disaster-recovery-tool

I am making an incremental backup of my Apache server's HTML directories over a cable modem connection at home. The MySQL databases are backed up whole because incremental backup is neither possible nor necessary (tables were small enough). I could have used ADSL just as well.

MySQL dumps located on the server have to be prepared in advance so that when the Rasp-Pi starts syncing, they are present. An external USB drive and a WiFi device are attached. It is possible to replace these with a thumb drive and a GSM modem. The monitor and the keyboard were removed after setup.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the RasPi StackExchange.  Link only answers are against site policy. Would you mind expanding on the answer, at least giving a summary of what needs to be done?

Comment: I have edited my original post. What do you think of it?